# What can I do when the Network Manager tray/panel icon stops responding?

Tags: network-manager, process

Sometimes the networking program (controlled via drop down menu from the wireless symbol in the top right of the screen) hangs on my laptop (ASUS U36JC).

I have tried "sudo killall NetworkManager", which didn't seem to affect it. What is the name of this program? How would you kill and/or restart it when it no longer responds?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you mean by hanging? It stops responding to mouse clicks? Or what?

Comment: How about `nm-applet`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo stop NetworkManager` followed by `sudo start NetworkManager` in a terminal when this occurs.

Comment: I mean that it no longer responds to interaction (mouse, keyboard).

Comment: Yes, Izx, that was it :D Now I can kill and restart it. Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't see you reply until now, Roland. Your answer is probably the best solution.